# Python code not reading Travis CI environment variables

Tags: python, travis-ci

I've added a environment variable to my Travis CI repository under the name `SECRET_KEY` as described in [this](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/#Defining-Variables-in-Repository-Settings) guide. When I deploy to GitHub and the git hook signals Travis and Travis then runs, I get a `KeyError` in the line:

```
SECRET_KEY = os.environ['SECRET_KEY']
```

Why is it not recognising the key?

**Edit**

After following advice in the comments to add `export SECRET_KEY=$SECRET_KEY` to the `.travis.yml` file I get the error `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.`

My `.travis.yml` file looks like this:

```
language: python
python:
    - "2.7"

install: pip install -r requirements.txt

script:
    - export SECRET_KEY=$SECRET_KEY
    - python manage.py test

secure: <long encrypted string>
```

The `secure` parameter refers to [this](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/#Encrypted-Variables) guide which I first tried to no avail.

Comment: Post the snippet of your `.travis.yml` file, edit it and remove any sensitive stuff before posting it here. But show where you define the variable and where you run your python code. Having said that if you run your code under `script:` "section" of the travis file you can do `SECRET_KEY=$SECRET_KEY ./python-file.py` or explicitly do `export SECRET_KEY=$SECRET_KEY` on its own line (still under `script:` section).

Comment: I've edited my question accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Change your travis file to define the secure encrypted key under `env.global` section as follows:

```
language: python
python:
    - "2.7"

install: pip install -r requirements.txt
env:
  global:
      secure: <long encrypted string>

script:
    - export SECRET_KEY=$SECRET_KEY
    - python manage.py test
```

Where `secure: <long encrypted string>` corresponds to your `$SECRET_KEY` that you generated with `travis encrypt 'SECRET_KEY=this-is-demo-password' --add`

Comment: Whenever I try `travis encrypt <secret key=key> -add` I get the error `NoMethodError: private method 'load' called for nil:NilClass`

Comment: That is another issue and not related to python at all. Its travis specific. You are having difficulties with creating a secure key? Did you install the travis utility using `sudo gem install travis` and after that typed `travis` for the first time just for travis to initialize?

Comment: It just gives me a list of available commands when I run `travis`.

Comment: Run the command without `--add` and it should print the secure key in terminal: `travis encrypt 'SECRET_KEY=foobar'`. If that works you can copy it and paste it in your `.travis.yml` as shown in the answer. If not its a travis bug. Look at: https://github.com/travis-ci/travis.rb/issues/261 and also ensure your system is up to date.